# Dynamic Background image depending on orientation

Tags: jquery, dynamic, background-image

I'm trying to create a dynamic full page background image. I found the DirectorySlider plugin which worked fine for regular images but I can't seem to modify it for Background-images.

I want to create a background-image because the image must fit in the browser view (full width and height), so I was thinking to use the background-size: 100% 100% property.

the live website is visible at: [Belgianscentacademy - test](http://preview.belgianscentacademy.com)

Here is the code that I have so far.

```js
(function($){
   var directorySlider = function(element, options)
   {
       var elem = $(element),
           obj = this,
           elemId = elem[0].id;

       // Merge config settings
       var config = $.extend({
           animation: 'slide',
           filebase: 'slide_',
           extension: 'jpg',
           speed: 1000,
           timeout: 4000,
           directory: null,
           numslides: null,
           height: null,
           width: null
       }, options || {});

       // set slideshow dimensions if set
       if (config.height) {
        $(elem).css('height', config.height);
       }
       if (config.width) {
        $(elem).css('width', config.width);
       }

       $(elem).css('overflow', 'hidden');

       // Get slides
       var slides = [],
       slideNumber = 1;

       while(slideNumber <= config.numslides){
         slides.push($(".background-image").css("background-image", 'url(' + config.directory + config.filebase + slideNumber + '.' + config.extension + ');' ) );
         slideNumber++;
       }

       // append slideshow
       // apply slide wrap 1st
       var slideWrap = $('<div class="' + elemId + '-slide-wrap" ></div>');
           slideWrap.appendTo(elem);

        // append slide and position absolutley
       $.each(slides, function(index, val) {
         $(val).css({
           position: 'absolute',
           top: 0,
           left: 0
         }).appendTo(slideWrap);
       });

    setInterval(function(){
       var firstSlide = elem.find('img:first-child'),
           lastSlide = elem.find('img:last-child');
       // Apply animation
       switch(config.animation){

        case 'fade':
            $(lastSlide).animate({
              opacity: 0},
              config.speed, function() {
              $(this).insertBefore(firstSlide).css('opacity', 1);
            });
        break;

        case 'uncover':
            lastSlide.animate({
              marginLeft: -$(this).width()},
              config.speed, function() {
              $(this).insertBefore(firstSlide).css('marginLeft', 0);
            });
            break;
        default:
            $(lastSlide).animate({
              opacity: 0},
              config.speed, function() {
              $(this).insertBefore(firstSlide).css('opacity', 1);
            });
       }
    }, config.timeout);

   };

   $.fn.directorySlider = function(options)
   {
       return this.each(function()
       {
           var element = $(this);

           // Return early if this element already has a plugin instance
           if (element.data('directoryslider')) return;

           // pass options to plugin constructor
           var directoryslider = new directorySlider(this, options);

           // Store plugin object in this element's data
           element.data('directoryslider', directoryslider);

       });
   };
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.background-image {
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  background-image: url('../backgroundimages/verticaal/slide_1.jpg');
  background-color: red;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider-main"></div>

<div class="w-section background-image">
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  

  if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
    alert("portrait!");
    $('#slider-main').directorySlider({
    animation: 'fade',
    filebase: 'slide_',
    directory: '../backgroundimages/verticaal/',
    extension: 'jpg',
    numslides: 2,
    height: sizeContent
});
}
});
  </script>
```

Comment: You can do this in CSS. A combination of a media query to detect the orientation, and `background-size: cover` should work.

Comment: Would this mean that the images will always be resized to fit the display without cutting away parts of the image? Another part of the problem is that the above script works for regular images but not for the bg-image.

Comment: Yes, if you used `background-size: contain`. You should note that this will stretch the height/width ratio of the image and may look odd. `cover` is better for this reason.